# Xampp doesn't reload changes when files get updated

Tags: xampp, localhost, opencart

When I copy live opencart website to the local xampp, can't show any updates

I had a working local copy on my localhost, but I needed to get the most updated copy from the live site. So I copied the live site and the live db(in workbench). Then I changed config files(both admin and catalog). The website works perfectly on local browser, but the changes I do through code doesn't show on browser. But when I change my database to the old local db I can see updates.

No errors showing on browser

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"As a developer, or store owner, you may make a change somewhere in your online shop and not see that change being applied on the front-end. In that case you probably need to clear your caches, but there is more than one so it helps to be aware of what caches there are and how to clear them."
https://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/how-to-clear-all-caches-in-opencart-3-0-2-0/

Comment: Thank you so much Paul, you saved my day... I read your article and cleared Twig/SASS (Template) cache and solved the problem

Comment: I'm very glad to hear this :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the above issue using Twig/SASS (Template) clear cache method. I have to do this for each update. But then I got another issue - the default image on product category doesn't show up. Image src shows as unknown, which fetch from cache folder. Any solution for this please?